# How to Search Data in XML based on multiple search criteria defined by HTML Multi selection Dropdown using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, drop-down-menu

I have an application under development with the following scenario

There are 4 multi-select dropdowns:

1. DropDown1: Market Offering, which has `<option>`'s as SS, IE and HIX
2. DropDown2: Technology, which has values based on the optgroup i.e Application is the optgroup label and then its corresponding values e.g Java, Java EE. There are 4 such optgroups
3. DropDown3: Business Process - Specific to the business scenario but again list of select options
4. DropDown4: Project Scope : This too has multiple options which the user can select.

The user can select multiple values from the dropdowns above, none of them are mandatory and then click on Search Button

These values are used to search inside an xml file(DataSets.xml, given below) and the response should be Array of `<State>` elements within a given `<DataSet>`, If there are multiple `<DataSet>` elements that match the query, the resultant array should contain all of the `<State>` element values:

```
<DataSets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://DataSets.xsd">
     <DataSet>
           <MarketOffering>IE</MarketOffering>
           <Technology>
                 <Application>J2EE</Application>
                 <Database>Oracle</Database>
                 <Middleware>MuleESB</Middleware>
                 <Reporting>Crystal Reports</Reporting>
                 <Correspondence>HPEx</Correspondence>
                 <RulesEngine>Corticon</RulesEngine>
           </Technology>
           <BizProcess>Registration</BizProcess>
           <ProjectScope>SNAP</ProjectScope>
           <State>MT</State>
           <State>RI</State>
     </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
           <MarketOffering>SS</MarketOffering>
           <Technology>
                 <Application>.NET</Application>
                 <Database>Oracle</Database>
                 <Middleware>MuleESB</Middleware>
                 <Reporting>CrystalReports</Reporting>
                 <Correspondence>HPEx</Correspondence>
                 <RulesEngine>Corticon</RulesEngine>
           </Technology>
           <BizProcess>Registration</BizProcess>
           <ProjectScope>SNAP</ProjectScope>
           <State>SD</State>
           <State>AZ</State>
     </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

The condition of filtering is:

1. Options selected within the dropdown has a "OR" condition i.e if either of the values given in the dropdown e.g MarketOffering i.e SS, IE or HIX is found in the XML, its a match.
2. Criteria across dropdown becomes AND condition i.e MarketOffering as 'IE' AND Technology as 'J2EE' and ProjectScope as 'SNAP'

Following is the JQuery which I have written(Pretty naive I know, this is what happens when a Java Developer writes jQuery... :-)) uptil now but this isnt achieving all that I require. Can someone please help me in solving this riddle:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".searchLink").click(function () {

            var solutionTypeArray = [];
            $('#solutionType option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                solutionTypeArray[i] = $(selected).val();
            });

            var applicationTypeArray = [];
            var databaseTypeArray = [];
            var middlewareArray = [];
            var correspondenceArray = [];
            var reportingArray = [];
            var rulesArray = [];

            $('#technology option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {

                if ($(selected).parent().prop('label') == 'Application') {
                    applicationTypeArray[i] = $(selected).val();
                } else if ($(selected).parent().prop('label') == 'Database') {
                    databaseTypeArray[i] = $(selected).val();
                } else if ($(selected).parent().prop('label') == 'Middleware') {
                    middlewareArray[i] = $(selected).val();
                } else if ($(selected).parent().prop('label') == 'Reporting') {
                    reportingArray[i] = $(selected).val();
                } else if ($(selected).parent().prop('label') == 'Correspondence') {
                    correspondenceArray[i] = $(selected).val();
                } else if ($(selected).parent().prop('label') == 'Rules Engine') {
                    rulesArray[i] = $(selected).val();
                }
            });

            var bizProcessArray = [];
            $('#bizProcesses option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                bizProcessArray[i] = $(selected).val();
            });

            var projectScopeArray = [];
            $('#projectScope option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                projectScopeArray[i] = $(selected).val();
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "DataSets.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    //Read the DataSet element and find the children's value to compare with HTML values
                    var $dataset = $(xml).find("DataSet");

                    $dataset.each(function () {

                        var marketOfferingFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("MarketOffering").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), solutionTypeArray) != -1) {
                                marketOfferingFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var bizProcessFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("BizProcess").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), bizProcessArray) != -1) {
                                bizProcessFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var projectScopeFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("ProjectScope").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), projectScopeArray) != -1) {
                                projectScopeFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var applicationTypeFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("Application").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), applicationTypeArray) != -1) {
                                applicationTypeFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var databaseTypeFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("Database").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), databaseTypeArray) != -1) {
                                databaseTypeFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var middelWareFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("Middleware").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), middlewareArray) != -1) {
                                middelWareFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var correspondenceFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("Correspondence").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), correspondenceArray) != -1) {
                                correspondenceFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var reportingFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("Reporting").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), reportingArray) != -1) {
                                reportingFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        var rulesFlag = false;
                        $dataset.find("RulesEngine").each(function () {
                            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), rulesArray) != -1) {
                                rulesFlag = true;
                            }
                        });

                        if (marketOfferingFlag || bizProcessFlag || projectScopeFlag || applicationTypeFlag
                               || databaseTypeFlag || rulesFlag || correspondenceFlag || reportingFlag || middelWareFlag) {

                            var array = $dataset.find("State").map(function () {
                                return $(this).text();
                            }).get();

                            alert(array)
                        }

                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("XML File : DataSets.xml cannot be loaded successfuly. Please check the path and try again.");
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

Hope someone would be able to help me out.

Thanks

Edit: Providing the snapshot of the exact requirement:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your HTML for this as well? Its a little hard to understand what you need.

Comment: CodeGodie, Its a proprietery code and hence cant post the HTML. Isnt the requirement quite clear? let me know if I can explain it better?

Comment: well its not clear to me, thats why im asking. What is your desired output? From what I understand, you have select dropdowns in the HTML and you need to compare each option to your XML, if theres a match, you want to set OR conditions?... thats where im confused. Explain it better so that we can help. The more info you provide the better.

Comment: I'm sorry. So, user can select multiple option within a dropdown and search should return results if any(OR) of them match. However,  when more than one dropdown has value, it should AND the values and then search e.g Dropdown 1 Values AND DropDown2 Values. Hope its clear now.

Comment: a bit better. Let me see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this:

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <select id="solutionType" multiple>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>SS</option>
        <option>IE</option>
        <option>HIX</option>
    </select>

    <select id="technology" multiple>
        <option>0</option>
        <optgroup label="Application">
            <option>JAVA</option>
            <option>JEE</option>
            <option>J2EE</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Database">
            <option>Oracle</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <select id="bizProcesses" multiple>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>Registration</option>
    </select>

    <select id="projectScope" multiple>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>SNAP</option>
    </select>
    <button class="searchLink">Search</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".searchLink").click(function() {
        var solutionType = $("#solutionType").val();


        var techOpts = new Array();
        $('#technology :selected').each(function() {
            var obj = {
                label: $(this).parent().attr("label"),
                value: $(this).val()
            };
            techOpts.push(obj);
        });


        var bizProcesses = $("#bizProcesses").val();
        var projectScope = $("#projectScope").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "DataSets.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var $dataset = $(xml).find("DataSet");
                $dataset.each(function(k) {
                    var $dataset_element = $(this);
                    var arr = new Array();

                    if (solutionType != 0) {
                        var solArr = new Array();
                        $.each(solutionType, function(k) {
                            if ($dataset_element.find("MarketOffering").text() === solutionType[k]) {
                                //solArr.push(solutionType[k]);
                                solArr.push(true);
                            } else {
                                solArr.push(false);
                            }
                        });
                        arr.push(solArr);
                    } else {
                        arr.push(false);
                    }

                    if (techOpts[0].value != 0) {
                        var techArr = new Array();
                        $.each(techOpts, function(k, v) {
                            if ($dataset_element.find(v.label).text() === v.value) {
                                techArr.push(true);
                            } else {
                                techArr.push(false);
                            }
                        });
                        arr.push(techArr);
                    } else {
                        arr.push(false);
                    }

                    if (bizProcesses != 0) {
                        var bizArr = new Array();
                        $.each(bizProcesses, function(k) {
                            if ($dataset_element.find("BizProcess").text() === bizProcesses[k]) {
                                //bizArr.push(bizProcesses[k]);
                                bizArr.push(true);
                            } else {
                                bizArr.push(false);
                            }
                        });
                        arr.push(bizArr);
                    } else {
                        arr.push(false);
                    }

                    if (projectScope != 0) {
                        var projhArr = new Array();
                        $.each(projectScope, function(k) {
                            if ($dataset_element.find("ProjectScope").text() === projectScope[k]) {
                                //projhArr.push(projectScope[k]);
                                projhArr.push(true);
                            } else {
                                projhArr.push(false);
                            }
                        });
                        arr.push(projhArr);
                    } else {
                        arr.push(false);
                    }

                    var foundArr = new Array();
                    $.each(arr, function(k, v) {

                        if (v) {
                            if (v.length > 0 && $.inArray(true, v) > -1) {
                                foundArr.push(true);
                            } else {
                                foundArr.push(false);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if (foundArr.length > 0 && $.inArray(false, foundArr) == -1) {
                        var array = $dataset_element.find("State").map(function() {
                            return $(this).text();
                        }).get();
                        alert(array);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("XML File : DataSets.xml cannot be loaded successfuly. Please check the path and try again.");
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I would do. Try it and let me know:

HTML:

```
    <select id="solutionType">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>SS</option>
        <option>IE</option>
        <option>HIX</option>
    </select>

    <select id="technology">
        <option>0</option>
        <optgroup label="Application">
            <option>JAVA</option>
            <option>JEE</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Database">
            <option>Oracle</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <select id="bizProcesses">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>Registration</option>
    </select>

    <select id="projectScope">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>SNAP</option>
    </select>
    <button class="searchLink">Search</button>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".searchLink").click(function() {
            var solutionType = $("#solutionType").val();

            var technology = $("#technology").val();
            var technology_label = $('#technology :selected').parent().attr('label');

            var bizProcesses = $("#bizProcesses").val();
            var projectScope = $("#projectScope").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    var $dataset = $(xml).find("DataSet");
                    $dataset.each(function(k) {

                        var arr = new Array();

                        if(solutionType != 0){
                            if ($(this).find("MarketOffering").text() === solutionType) {
                                arr.push(solutionType);
                            } else {
                                arr.push(false);
                            }
                        }

                        if(technology != 0){
                            if ($(this).find(technology_label).text() === technology) {
                                arr.push(technology);
                            } else {
                                arr.push(false);
                            }
                        }

                        if(bizProcesses != 0){
                            if ($(this).find("BizProcess").text() === bizProcesses) {
                                arr.push(bizProcesses);
                            } else {
                                arr.push(false);
                            }
                        }

                        if(projectScope != 0){
                            if ($(this).find("ProjectScope").text() === projectScope) {
                                arr.push(projectScope);
                            } else {
                                arr.push(false);
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(arr);


                        if($.inArray(false, arr) == -1){
                            var array = $(this).find("State").map(function() {
                                return $(this).text();
                            }).get();
                            alert(array);
                        }

                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                     alert("XML File : DataSets.xml cannot be loaded successfuly. Please check the path and try again.");
                }
           });
        });

   });
   </script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thankyou so much for taking time out on this. This works perfectly fine when I select EXACT data which is present in the DataSets.xml, However, seems the code has been written with a thinking that user will ONLY select one of the values in dropdown which isn't true. Even if the user selects just 1 dropdown with multiple values( e.g SS and IE), it should return values there are two <DataSet> elements which match with the search criteria. I have updated the question with additional snapshot which will provide details on the requirement even better. Thanks a lot for all the help till now.

Comment: You're welcome, no problem, I love doing this. I have a question though, when you multi select(for example SS, IE, HIX) on your first dropdown, do all the options need to be present in the XML in order to give you the search results? for example, what if the user selects SS, IE, HIX, but the DataSet only contains IE and SS, what is the expected result?

Comment: Its not necessary to have all of the selected values, if only SS and IE are available, just those States will be returned. Same applies to all the other dropdowns as well.

Comment: Hi CodeGodie, were you able to figure out how to go about this? I am really confused about this. The only way I can think of is to create an array of all the selected values and then search the values inside the XML? Let me know if you have any other thoughts or were able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I was too busy this weekend. I will take a look at this and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Hi CodeGodie, how do you actually get so much of time in writing this amazing code! I used the updated script and somehow there are some JS errors which I am not able to understand
1. techOpts[0] is undefined 2. If I comment out of the techopts section, then it says "a is null", I figured out this error comes when I keep any dropdown blank i.e unselected ( similar to the screenshot I attached earlier. All the dropdowns are optional and hence user can keep any of the dropdowns unselected. Thankyou again for all the help and looking forward for further assistance.

Comment: I have updated one more screenshot of what all scenarios I am looking that should work, may be that can help you in understanding the requirement even better. Also, The '<DataSet>' element has children which are "unbounded" which means there can be 1 to many <Application> elements or <DataBase> elements, except for Technology which is the top level element.

Comment: No problem. I do this as a hobby. All you have to do is have your defaults set to zero. or false, or "None".. whichever you want. then set your conditional if statements to ignore if thats not set. This will fix your "not null" errors. Hope this helps. Dont forget to accept my answer with the green check mark:) thank you.

Comment: Woooohoooooooooooo!!!!! You've lived up to your name CodeGodie.. God of Code :) I am upvoting your answer, this is now solved! All my scenarios are working as expected.